# UseState always return Previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I select a value it always returns the previous value. Not returning which I selected.
I want, when I select value it quickly reflects and store current value.

```
const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(15);

const handleChange = async (event) => {
    let data = (document.getElementById("dropzonee")).value
   
    setPostsPerPage(data)
    console.log(postsPerPage)

}


           <span>Rows Per Page</span>
            <select id="dropzonee"
                name="changedValue"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={postsPerPage}
             >
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `event.target.value`

```
const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(15);

const handleChange = async (event) => {
    setPostsPerPage(event.target.value)
    console.log(postsPerPage)
}
```

or if you don't use `asyns/await`, use like this

```
const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(15);

           <span>Rows Per Page</span>
            <select id="dropzonee"
                name="changedValue"
                onChange={(e) => setPostsPerPage(e.target.value)}
                value={postsPerPage}
             >
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`let data = (document.getElementById("dropzonee")).value`,

try

`let data = event.target.value`.

It will always show selected value. But even so, console.log(postsPerPage) will always log previous value, because setState function works asynchronously, and it that moment state didn't really updated. Just log event.target.value to ensure

Comment: It's not work .. result same to return previous value